# BibTeX non-hierarchical keywords (tagging) for classification

Tags: bibtex, jabref

BibTeX entries exported from online databases such as IEEExplore have keyword fields containing information that was decided by the authors or editors. However, I want to define my own non-hierarchical classification (i.e., [tags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_(metadata)) or custom keywords) to use in my BibTeX database, without clearing the original keywords field.

What BibTeX field should I use for such classifications? Ideally, I'd like to be able to add tags and query entries of my tags with a tool such as [JabRef](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/). There's a [video that explains tagging in Mendeley](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Inn1QpFgGv4), but I'd like to achieve the same with some BibTeX software.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use arbitrary keywords that are not yet defined. They will be ignored by `bibtex`.

In JabRef, you can add those fields in `Options/Set up general fields`.

Comment: I edited my question to reflect that "tagging" is an operation to easily add non-hierarchical classification metadata. The suggestion you gave allows me to manually edit those keywords in a field, but "tagging" as I'd like to use it doesn't seem to work in JabRef with that method.

Comment: "Tagging" as I want it to work in JabRef is possible! Here are the quick steps: **View > Toggle groups interface**. Create a **New group** and name it with the classification you want, e.g., empirical study. Assign **Dynamically group entries by searching a field for a keyword** and leave **Hierarchical context** as **Independent group**. Under **Options** specify **Field** with tags (for arbitrary keywords). Under **Keyword** put the corresponding tag value, e.g., empirical study. Dragging entries to the Group will add the keyword to the tag field. Clicking the group shows tagged entries.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator Your solution is very hard to follow.  Can you please explain in more detail in an answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Adding the answer from [a comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197346/bibtex-non-hierarchical-keywords-tagging-for-classification#comment457525_197348) here as well:

Tagging in the sense to add non-hierarchical keywords can be achieved with groups. They can be arranged hierarchically, but are non-exclusive.

A different option is to use [keywords](https://docs.jabref.org/finding-sorting-and-cleaning-entries/keywords). However, they seem harder to use, especially when trying to easily access all documents with a certain keyword (can be done with [search](https://docs.jabref.org/finding-sorting-and-cleaning-entries/search), but not that easy).

What one can also do is to use keywords together with groups and have all documents with a certain keyword automatically be added to a corresponding group. That would be duplicate work, though.